# How to easily think through the process of recursion in Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I understand all the basics of Recursion and how it is managed like a stack. However, while working with insertion and deletion operation in Binary Search Tree I had difficulties to wrap the thing around my head. It was taking lots of time to implement the different examples (in my head) following the given codes. I really need a linear way of thinking through the concept. So I need some useful resource to recapitulate Recursion.

Binary Search Tree:
Node:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};
```

Creating New Nodes:

```
struct Node* newNode(int val)
{
    struct Node* temp=(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data=val;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    return temp;
};
```

Insertion:

```
struct Node* insertion(struct Node* root,int val)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return newNode(val);
    else if(val<=root->data)
    {
        root->left=insertion(root->left,val);
    }
    else{
        root->right=insertion(root->right,val);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Find Minimum:

```
struct Node* minimum(struct Node* root)
{
    while(root->left!=NULL)
        root=root->left;
    return root;
}
```

Deletion:

```
struct Node* Delete(struct Node *root, int data) {
    if(root == NULL) return root; 
    else if(data < root->data) root->left = Delete(root->left,data);
    else if (data > root->data) root->right = Delete(root->right,data);
    else {
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) { 
            delete root;
            root = NULL;
        }
        else if(root->left == NULL) {
            struct Node *temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        else if(root->right == NULL) {
            struct Node *temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        else { 
            struct Node *temp = minimum(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = Delete(root->right,temp->data);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Draw a tree on paper with a few nodes already inserted. Then, pick a value and run through the logic of your insert function, pointing to whichever node is currently pointed at by the current insert's root.

Comment: I recommend using a visualization site such as https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BST.html. By reading the code line by line while inserting and deleting interactively, I think it's easier to understand.